# deploy module to remote server that is running node.js

Tags: node.js, server, module

I'm working on my app.js in node.js 
     -- trying to deploy server-side script.
    Many fine node.js modules need a require('something');
    I use NPM locally, which works for require, as modules are nicely visible in the local node_modules folder structure. but now I'm ready to upload or bundle to a host. I can't run npm on this hosted server.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
will result in
Error: Cannot find module 'hapi'
because I don't know how to copy/install/bundle/ftp files to my host.
Hapi is just an example. Most anything that has a require will need something on the host.
I used webpack to create a server side bundle.js but just sticking bundle.js under /node_modules doesn't do anything.
Most modules have a complex folder structure underneath --- I'm trying to avoid copying a ton of folders and files under /node_modules.  Ideally, I want to combine the modules into a bundle.js and have those modules visible to app.js
but I am open to other ideas.
```

I have not yet tried using webpack to bundle app.js TOGETHER with the various modules.  Have you had luck with that approach?
    thanks.

```
I've tried to upload hapi files a folder-ful at a time, reaching a new require('something') error at every step.


'use strict';
const Hapi = require('hapi'); // <-- how can I deploy hapi on my node.js server?
// Create a server with a host and port
const server=Hapi.server({
    host:'localhost',
    port:8000
});
// Add the route
server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/hello',
    handler:function(request,h) {

        return'hello world';
    }
});

// Start the server
async function start() {

    try {
        await server.start();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
};

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    one approach that worked:  using webpack to bundle the back end js.
    thanks to 
    https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back- 
end-b95f1b429810

    the aha moment... run webpack to create bundle-back.js then
    tie bundle-back.js to my node server
    **You start your backend server with ‘bundle-back.js’ using:
        node bundle-back.js 

    In other words, include app.js in the bundle with the modules.
```